# In which medium is Potassium Permanganate a better oxidising agent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

I was in chemistry class just now, and my chemistry teacher gave us three reactions:

Reaction 1: $\ce{MnO4^- + e- -> + MnO4^2- (basic medium)}$

Reaction 2: $\ce{MnO4^- + 4H+ + 3e- -> + MnO2 + 2H2O (neutral or nearly neutral medium)}$

Reaction 3: $\ce{MnO4^- + 8H+ + 5e- -> + Mn^2+ + 4H2O (acidic medium)}$

with n-factors of $n_1=1$, $n_2=3$, and $n_3=5$ respectively.

Now, the problem arose when my teacher stated that $\ce{KMnO4}$ was the best oxidising agent in the acidic medium. He said that this is due to the fact that $\ce{KMnO4}$ had the greatest n-factor when it was in the acidic medium. I decided to do a bit of fact-checking in my book (NCERT, which is the standard book we use in India) and I came across the fact that each of these reactions has reduction potentials of $E^⦵_1 = +0.56 \mathrm{V}$, $E^⦵_2 = +1.69 \mathrm{V}$, and $E^⦵_3 = +1.52 \mathrm{V}$ respectively, which lead me to conclude that instead, $\ce{KMnO4}$ is a better oxidising agent in the neutral medium, if we go by the experimental data of reduction potentials.

Besides this, my book also mentions that: "Although many reactions can be understood by consideration of redox potential, kinetics of the reaction is also an important factor. Permanganate at $\ce{[H+]}$ $=$ $1$ should oxidise water but in practice the reaction is extremely slow unless either Manganese (II) ions are present or the temperature is raised." It does not elaborate further, but this gives me a hint that somehow, the kinetics when it comes to this reaction matter as well.

An addition from my side: if we were to calculate the Standard Gibbs Free Energy from the given redox potentials, we would find that the most negative Gibbs Free Energy would be for the third reaction. Would this in any case have an effect? Since it's "more spontaneous", could we consider that it's a better oxidising agent in that case?

So my final question is, is the book correct or is my teacher correct? And if my teacher is correct, then how should I know to judge the oxidising nature through reduction potentials or through the n-factor? It seems that my teacher is giving more weight to the stoichiometry, and the book to the kinetics and thermodynamics.

Comment: Define better, as there are multiple possible weighted criteria. (Thermodynamics, kinetics, stoichiometry ratios, stability of reagents, price etc). Reduction potentials are just one of them.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "possible weighted criteria" please?

Comment: Both can be correct because "better" is subjective parameter. The book and the teacher could use different criteria set and their different importance and therefore their result need not be the same.

Comment: Related: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281434219_Applications_of_Potassium_Permanganate_in_the_Oxidative_Degradation_of_Trichloroethylene

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal Not in the title. And the body considers thermodynamics, kinetics and stoichometry. Each of them contributes to "better". The teacher gives more weight to stoichiometry, the book to thermodynamics and kinetics.

Comment: @Poutnik Alright, got it. I have one more question if the Nernst Equation affects anything, I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: Both the Nernst equation and acid-base equilibrii affect redox reactions. They have two sides: the oxidant and reductant. If KMnO4 gets weaker and reductant is stronger with higher pH, is KMnO4 better or worse oxidant at higher pH?

Comment: See also [commons.wikimedia.org - Mn Pourbaix diagram.png](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mn_pourbaix_diagram.png) // The two dashed inclined lines are pH dependent potentials for oxidation and reduction of water.